# quarterly returns and timeseries in r

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame that i imported from excel of the form shown below. I am trying to generate a time series plot in r however when i convert the df into ts, it is also converted into a matrix and so i get a matrix plot when all i want is a simple time series line plot. Any help is appreciated. Ive done the following:

```
series1 <- read.csv("NCREIF.csv", head=T)
series1$Year <- as.Date(paste(1978:2015, "01", "01",sep="-"), 
               format="%Y-%m-%d")
series1$Year <- format(as.Date(paste(1978:2015, "01", "01",sep="-"), 
             format="%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y" )
series1 <-  ts(series1)
plot(series1)


Year    Quarter 1   Quarter 2   Quarter 3   Quarter 4
1978    2.90%   3.07%   3.39%   5.89%
1979    3.81%   4.32%   4.75%   6.19%
1980    5.54%   2.36%   3.79%   5.32%
1981    2.96%   4.23%   3.21%   5.29%
```

Comment: The `year` part is reproducible where as the value is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to split the data and time-index argument in `ts()`:

```
dat <- rnorm(38)
series1 <- ts(dat, start=1978, end=2015)
plot(series1)
```

the Year variable in your code is treated as a time-series and you end up with a plot of both. 
If you have more series in your data-file and only want a single plot of all, then use the `plot.type` argument of `ts.plot`:

```
plot(series, plot.type = "single")
```